# Get NSURL for image data of contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, nsurl, abaddressbook

I need to get the reference URL for the stored image of a contact.

If I'm getting an image from a `UIImagePickerController`, I can get that simply by doing this.

`NSURL *imageURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];`

But how do I get this NSURL for an image of a contact from the Address Book?

`UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:CFBridgingRelease(ABPersonCopyImageData(ref))];`

i.e. get the reference URL for `contactImage`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` argument in your question is not an `NSURL`, but an `ABRecordRef`, i.e. the reference to an address book record. You had first to open the address book using code like

```
CFErrorRef error = nil;
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions (NULL, &error);
```

and then to find the required person using e.g.

```
ABRecordRef ref = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID (addressBookRef,recordID);
```

This gives you the required `ref`.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, perhaps I was not clear enough. I understand that `ref` is an `ABRecordRef`. My objective is to get the `NSURL` of the contact image obtained from the `ABRecordRef`.

Comment: Sorry, this was not clear to me. I believe you cannot get such an NSURL. As far as I know, these images are stored in a database, and are not accessible via URLs.

Comment: I see, are you aware of any alternative? I am using a third-party SDK, which makes use of the `NSURL` to send the image.

Comment: Maybe you could save the image to a temp file, use this URL, and delete the file in the callback? I know this is ugly, but I don't have another idea...

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, guess I'll have to do that for now. Thanks for your help!